# Shortcut to intel compiler directory to use in makefile

Tags: c++, intel, qmake

I compiled my program with intel C++ compiler for windows (from Intel Composer 2011), and got an error message that libmmdd.lib cannot be found. I googled this problem, and some people said that I have to reinstall my compiler, and I did; however, that didn't resolve the problem, so I started looking in the intel compiler directory, and found that this file (and other required libraries as well) are located at

%CompilerDirectory%\compiler\lib\ia32

It doesn't make sense to write in the make file the whole absolute path of the libraries, so I started searching, and I could only find that %mklroot% points to the math kernel directory. And even with a -L%mklroot%/../compiler/lib/ia32 approach for linking I couldn't link to the libraries correctly, so eventually I did a lame move to solve the problem, which is, I copied every file the linker asks for to the source directory, and so was the problem temporarily solved.

Since this way of solving the problem isn't the best one, I wonder if there's a way to link to those libraries without having to copy the files. It's strange because the compiler should find its own libraries alone, but... I don't know...!

Any ideas? is there something like, %compilerroot%, that points to the compiler directory and that I could put in my makefile (or actually my qmake, since I'm using Qt).

Thanks for any efforts :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `%mklroot%` try `$$(mklroot)` or `$(mklroot)`.

You can find the explanation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#variables):

> Variables can be used to store the contents of environment variables.
>   These can be evaluated at the time that qmake is run, or included in
>   the generated Makefile for evaluation when the project is built.
>
> To obtain the contents of an environment value when qmakeis run, use
>   the $$(...) operator:
>
> DESTDIR = $$(PWD)
>    message(The project will be installed in $$DESTDIR)
>
> In the above assignment, the value of the PWD environment variable is
>   read when the project file is processed.
>
> To obtain the contents of an environment value at the time when the
>   generated Makefile is processed, use the $(...) operator:
>
> DESTDIR = $$(PWD)
>   message(The project will be installed in $$DESTDIR)
>
> DESTDIR = $(PWD)
>    message(The project will be installed in the value of PWD)
>    message(when the Makefile is processed.)
>
> In the above assignment, the value of PWD is read immediately when the
>   project file is processed, but $(PWD) is assigned to DESTDIR in the
>   generated Makefile. This makes the build process more flexible as long
>   as the environment variable is set correctly when the Makefile is
>   processed.

EDIT:
It is strange that neither $$(mklroot) nor $(mklroot) gave you the result you would expect. I did a simple test to verify what I wrote above:

1. Opened a Command Prompt
2. Created a new environment variable 'mklroot' with a test value: `set mklroot=C:\intel_libs`
3. Verified the result of the previos step: `echo %mklroot%`. I got `C:\intel_libs`
4. Placed your 3 qmake functions at the end of my .pro file:
   warning($(%MKLROOT%))
   warning($(MKLROOT))
   warning($$(MKLROOT))
5. Ran qmake: `qmake`. The result:
   `Project WARNING:`
   `Project WARNING: c:\intel_libs`
   `Project WARNING: c:\intel_libs`

As you can see the 2nd and the 3rd warning() displayed the string I set to the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this and let you know how it goes. I'm sorry I'm moving now and can't really try it immediately.

Comment: No one of these commands in qmake gave the correct paths when qmake is run


warning($(%MKLROOT%))
warning($(MKLROOT))
warning($$(MKLROOT))

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's strange. I'm going to get to a computer having a development environment tomorrow. Then I'll check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Waiting for your answer :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I didn't see that the installer didn't define MKLROOT in my environment varibles. My mistake! Thanks a lot for your time. :-)